# Is being descriptive considered as more readable code, or should you always prioritize 'less code is more' in Python?

Tags: python, readability

For example, we have two methods that want to get the median of the lengths of the words in a sentence string input (this is just a simple example):

```
def get_median(sentence):
    words = tokenize(sentence)
    lengths_of_words = [len(word) for word in words]
    median = statistics.median(lengths_of_words)
    return median
```

This method is 4 lines long, but describes every component.

Its counterpart is:

```
def get_median(sentence):
    return statistics.median([len(x) for x in tokenize(sentence)])
```

Even the second seems more pythonic and smooth, the first is more descriptive and compartmentalized. I can't seem to find a clear consensus on this, but what should be preferred generally and what is considered more readable? And why?

Comment: This question seems to be opinion based. For me the second one is more compact and readable. For others, it may be the one that lacks explanation.

Comment: You aren't limited to one or the either. You can use a combination of both, as you did in the first example where you primarily compartmentalized but did add some compacted code.

Comment: "or should you always prioritize 'less code is more' in Python?" NO. Readability is often inversely correlated to the number of lines. Pythonic does *not* mean "cram everything into a one-liner". Now, fundamentally, readability is *subjective*. But you should always ask yourself, "will I remember what I'm trying to do when I read this code again in a month? In a year?", remember, code is generally written once but read many times. Also, I always ask myself, "would a competent programmer who is a novice in Python understand this?"

Comment: I'd have a few comments, but they'd be more suitable for codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the second way is better because its way less cluttered. I think that if you concerned that someone might not understand what the code snipped does you could just write a comment above explaining it. Why have cluttered code when you can do the same thing in a way thats more appealing to the eye when reading?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As per [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) avoid answering questions like this which solicit opinions rather than facts in the future.

Comment: @IvoMori Thanks for the heads up! I’ll avoid answering them going forward.